# How to interpret "nearest source location" in the cumulativeCost-function of Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am wondering what [the documentation of `cumulativeCost()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_cumulative_cost) in GEE exactly means by "nearest source location".

1. "nearest" in terms of "the closest starting pixel, linearly computed" or
2. "nearest" in terms of "the closest in terms of cumulative cost" ?

For my analysis I would like to know if the algorithm already reduces the number of potential routes in advance (by choosing only 1 starting point in advance) OR if it first tries the routes from one pixel to all possible starting points, and then takes the value to the starting pixel with the lowest total cost. Does anyone have more detailed information on how the algorithm works in that case? Thanks.